# Post cache substitution doesn't work in VS2013

Tags: caching, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have used Post cache substitution  in a .Net4 application.
In Vs2013 when I run the application I get the following error:

"Post cache substitution is not compatible with modules in the IIS integrated pipeline that modify the response buffers"
But when I publish the application to IIS (v7) it works properly.
I searched and found the following url related to this error:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2014472
But it's for .NET2 and my application works in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

In your appSettings section of your web.config, you should add the following entry:

<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />

Turning off browser link gets rid of the error.